How can more code execute faster than executing fewer?
I implemented Algorithm DLX in Java 17. In addition to the implementation that delivers execution statistics, I wanted to provide a version without statistics to improve execution time. I was surprised that the version without statistics executes significantly slower (8% on the test machine) than the one with statistics.
I did many tests and reduced the problem to two different versions of a single method of a MatrixEntry.
Fast version (first line is line 77 in MatrixEntry.java):
int coverColumn() {
    int updates = 1;
    columnHead.right.left = columnHead.left;
    columnHead.left.right = columnHead.right;
    MatrixEntry<T> i = columnHead.lower;
    while (i != columnHead) {
        MatrixEntry<T> j = i.right;
        while (j != i) {
            updates++;
            j.lower.upper = j.upper;
            j.upper.lower = j.lower;
            j.columnHead.rowCount--;
            j = j.right;
        }
        i = i.lower;
    }
    return updates;
}

Slow version (first line is line 77 in MatrixEntry.java):
void coverColumn() {
    //int updates = 1;
    columnHead.right.left = columnHead.left;
    columnHead.left.right = columnHead.right;
    MatrixEntry<T> i = columnHead.lower;
    while (i != columnHead) {
        MatrixEntry<T> j = i.right;
        while (j != i) {
            //updates++;
            j.lower.upper = j.upper;
            j.upper.lower = j.lower;
            j.columnHead.rowCount--;
            j = j.right;
        }
        i = i.lower;
    }
    //return updates;
}

I also inspected the bytecode using javap -c MatrixEntry.class and there aren't any differences other than the expected additional instructions to create a variable on the stack, increment and return it.
To provide some context to the code: Every field access is an access to an object reference to another instance of MatrixEntry, except for the one to rowCount. rowCount is an integer field.
I ran the test on a linux machine with an otherwise idle Xeon E3-1220 v6 server (on my desktop the results were less stable). The Java method gets called more than 309,357,294 times and the inner loop gets executed 100,722,885,573 times per application run. I did 4 application executions with and without statistics in the method. The standard deviation between runs was about 4 seconds while each run with statistics took 22:19 and each run without statistics took 24:08 minutes.
The JVM is an OpenJDK:
openjdk version "17.0.13" 2024-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.13+11 (build 17.0.13+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.13+11 (build 17.0.13+11, mixed mode, sharing)

Further information about the implementation can be found in the github repository, even though I guess that this context information isn't necessary.
I'm quite puzzled about the results and tried returning 0 instead of letting the method return void. I even created a version where the updates counter gets incremented but the value isn't stored - this version was fastest of all (but I didn't let it run multiple times).
Can somebody explain the improved performance of the code with integrated counter?

Bytecode of fast version:
  int coverColumn();
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: istore_1
       2: aload_0
       3: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
       6: getfield      #17                 // Field right:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
       9: aload_0
      10: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      13: getfield      #13                 // Field left:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      16: putfield      #13                 // Field left:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      19: aload_0
      20: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      23: getfield      #13                 // Field left:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      26: aload_0
      27: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      30: getfield      #17                 // Field right:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      33: putfield      #17                 // Field right:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      36: aload_0
      37: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      40: getfield      #23                 // Field lower:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      43: astore_2
      44: aload_2
      45: aload_0
      46: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      49: if_acmpeq     116
      52: aload_2
      53: getfield      #17                 // Field right:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      56: astore_3
      57: aload_3
      58: aload_2
      59: if_acmpeq     108
      62: iinc          1, 1
      65: aload_3
      66: getfield      #23                 // Field lower:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      69: aload_3
      70: getfield      #20                 // Field upper:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      73: putfield      #20                 // Field upper:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      76: aload_3
      77: getfield      #20                 // Field upper:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      80: aload_3
      81: getfield      #23                 // Field lower:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      84: putfield      #23                 // Field lower:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      87: aload_3
      88: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      91: dup
      92: getfield      #7                  // Field rowCount:I
      95: iconst_1
      96: isub
      97: putfield      #7                  // Field rowCount:I
     100: aload_3
     101: getfield      #17                 // Field right:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
     104: astore_3
     105: goto          57
     108: aload_2
     109: getfield      #23                 // Field lower:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
     112: astore_2
     113: goto          44
     116: iload_1
     117: ireturn

Bytecode of slower version:
  void coverColumn();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
       4: getfield      #17                 // Field right:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
       7: aload_0
       8: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      11: getfield      #13                 // Field left:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      14: putfield      #13                 // Field left:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      17: aload_0
      18: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      21: getfield      #13                 // Field left:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      24: aload_0
      25: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      28: getfield      #17                 // Field right:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      31: putfield      #17                 // Field right:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      34: aload_0
      35: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      38: getfield      #23                 // Field lower:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      41: astore_1
      42: aload_1
      43: aload_0
      44: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      47: if_acmpeq     111
      50: aload_1
      51: getfield      #17                 // Field right:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      54: astore_2
      55: aload_2
      56: aload_1
      57: if_acmpeq     103
      60: aload_2
      61: getfield      #23                 // Field lower:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      64: aload_2
      65: getfield      #20                 // Field upper:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      68: putfield      #20                 // Field upper:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      71: aload_2
      72: getfield      #20                 // Field upper:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      75: aload_2
      76: getfield      #23                 // Field lower:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      79: putfield      #23                 // Field lower:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      82: aload_2
      83: getfield      #26                 // Field columnHead:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      86: dup
      87: getfield      #7                  // Field rowCount:I
      90: iconst_1
      91: isub
      92: putfield      #7                  // Field rowCount:I
      95: aload_2
      96: getfield      #17                 // Field right:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
      99: astore_2
     100: goto          55
     103: aload_1
     104: getfield      #23                 // Field lower:Lde/famiru/dlx/MatrixEntry;
     107: astore_1
     108: goto          42
     111: return


As suggested in the comments, I let the JVM print the assembly after C2 compilation using the hsdis plugin and the following JVM command line flags: -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints -XX:PrintAssemblyOptions=intel -XX:CompileCommand=print,*MatrixEntry.coverColumn
I tried extracting only the inner loop part of the assembly, as the whole assembly is quite long. Full assembly can be found in a separate gist.
Fast code including counter:
0x00007faf08f46705:   mov    r11,QWORD PTR [r15+0x350]
0x00007faf08f4670c:   mov    r8,QWORD PTR [rsp]
0x00007faf08f46710:   mov    r9d,DWORD PTR [r8+0x14]      ;*getfield columnHead {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@46 (line 82)
0x00007faf08f46714:   mov    r13d,DWORD PTR [r13+0x24]    ; ImmutableOopMap {r9=NarrowOop r13=NarrowOop [0]=Oop }
                                                          ;*goto {reexecute=1 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - (reexecute) de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@113 (line 92)
0x00007faf08f46718:   test   DWORD PTR [r11],eax          ;*goto {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@113 (line 92)
                                                          ;   {poll}
0x00007faf08f4671b:   cmp    r13d,r9d
0x00007faf08f4671e:   je     0x00007faf08f46806           ;*aload_2 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@52 (line 83)
0x00007faf08f46724:   mov    ebp,DWORD PTR [r13+0x1c]     ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007faf08f46b04
                                                          ;*getfield right {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@53 (line 83)
0x00007faf08f46728:   cmp    ebp,r13d
0x00007faf08f4672b:   je     0x00007faf08f46705           ;*if_acmpeq {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@59 (line 84)
0x00007faf08f4672d:   mov    r11,r13                      ;*aload_2 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@52 (line 83)
0x00007faf08f46730:   mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],r11
0x00007faf08f46735:   data16 data16 nop WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
                                                          ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@62 (line 85)
0x00007faf08f46740:   mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x20]     ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007faf08f46aee
                                                          ;*getfield upper {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@70 (line 86)
0x00007faf08f46743:   mov    r14d,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x24]    ;*getfield lower {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@66 (line 86)
0x00007faf08f46747:   test   r14d,r14d
0x00007faf08f4674a:   je     0x00007faf08f46a2c           ;*putfield left {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@16 (line 79)
0x00007faf08f46750:   cmp    BYTE PTR [r15+0x38],0x0
0x00007faf08f46755:   jne    0x00007faf08f4681c
0x00007faf08f4675b:   mov    DWORD PTR [r14+0x20],ebx
0x00007faf08f4675f:   mov    r11,r14
0x00007faf08f46762:   mov    r8,rbx
0x00007faf08f46765:   xor    r8,r11
0x00007faf08f46768:   shr    r8,0x14
0x00007faf08f4676c:   test   r8,r8
0x00007faf08f4676f:   je     0x00007faf08f4678f
0x00007faf08f46771:   test   ebx,ebx
0x00007faf08f46773:   je     0x00007faf08f4678f
0x00007faf08f46775:   shr    r11,0x9
0x00007faf08f46779:   movabs rdi,0x7faf1bba1000
0x00007faf08f46783:   add    rdi,r11
0x00007faf08f46786:   cmp    BYTE PTR [rdi],0x4
0x00007faf08f46789:   jne    0x00007faf08f46882           ;*putfield upper {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@73 (line 86)
0x00007faf08f4678f:   mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x20]     ;*getfield upper {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@77 (line 87)
0x00007faf08f46792:   test   ebx,ebx
0x00007faf08f46794:   je     0x00007faf08f46a38           ;*putfield left {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@16 (line 79)
0x00007faf08f4679a:   cmp    BYTE PTR [r15+0x38],0x0
0x00007faf08f4679f:   jne    0x00007faf08f4684f
0x00007faf08f467a5:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbx+0x24],r14d
0x00007faf08f467a9:   mov    r11,r14
0x00007faf08f467ac:   mov    r8,rbx
0x00007faf08f467af:   xor    r11,r8
0x00007faf08f467b2:   shr    r11,0x14
0x00007faf08f467b6:   test   r11,r11
0x00007faf08f467b9:   je     0x00007faf08f467da
0x00007faf08f467bb:   test   r14d,r14d
0x00007faf08f467be:   je     0x00007faf08f467da
0x00007faf08f467c0:   shr    r8,0x9
0x00007faf08f467c4:   movabs rdi,0x7faf1bba1000
0x00007faf08f467ce:   add    rdi,r8
0x00007faf08f467d1:   cmp    BYTE PTR [rdi],0x4
0x00007faf08f467d4:   jne    0x00007faf08f468cb           ;*putfield lower {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@84 (line 87)
0x00007faf08f467da:   mov    r11d,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x14]    ;*getfield columnHead {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@88 (line 88)
0x00007faf08f467de:   dec    DWORD PTR [r11+0xc]          ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007faf08f46af8
                                                          ;*putfield left {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@16 (line 79)
0x00007faf08f467e2:   mov    r11,QWORD PTR [r15+0x350]
0x00007faf08f467e9:   mov    ebp,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x1c]     ;*getfield right {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@101 (line 89)
0x00007faf08f467ec:   inc    r10d                         ; ImmutableOopMap {rbp=NarrowOop r13=NarrowOop [0]=Oop [8]=Oop }
                                                          ;*goto {reexecute=1 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - (reexecute) de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@105 (line 89)
0x00007faf08f467ef:   test   DWORD PTR [r11],eax          ;*goto {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@105 (line 89)
                                                          ;   {poll}
0x00007faf08f467f2:   cmp    ebp,r13d
0x00007faf08f467f5:   je     0x00007faf08f46705           ;*if_acmpeq {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@59 (line 84)

Slow code returning void:
0x00007f0628f5c10c:   mov    r10,QWORD PTR [r15+0x350]
0x00007f0628f5c113:   mov    r11,QWORD PTR [rsp]
0x00007f0628f5c117:   mov    r11d,DWORD PTR [r11+0x14]    ;*getfield columnHead {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@44 (line 82)
0x00007f0628f5c11b:   mov    r13d,DWORD PTR [r13+0x24]    ; ImmutableOopMap {r11=NarrowOop r13=NarrowOop [0]=Oop }
                                                          ;*goto {reexecute=1 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - (reexecute) de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@108 (line 92)
0x00007f0628f5c11f:   test   DWORD PTR [r10],eax          ;*goto {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@108 (line 92)
                                                          ;   {poll}
0x00007f0628f5c122:   cmp    r13d,r11d
0x00007f0628f5c125:   je     0x00007f0628f5c0f9           ;*aload_1 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@50 (line 83)
0x00007f0628f5c127:   mov    ebp,DWORD PTR [r13+0x1c]     ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007f0628f5c49c
                                                          ;*getfield right {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@51 (line 83)
0x00007f0628f5c12b:   cmp    ebp,r13d
0x00007f0628f5c12e:   je     0x00007f0628f5c10c           ;*if_acmpeq {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@57 (line 84)
0x00007f0628f5c130:   mov    r10,r13                      ;*aload_1 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@50 (line 83)
0x00007f0628f5c133:   mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],r10
0x00007f0628f5c138:   nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]    ;*aload_2 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@60 (line 86)
0x00007f0628f5c140:   mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x24]     ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007f0628f5c486
                                                          ;*getfield lower {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@61 (line 86)
0x00007f0628f5c143:   mov    r14d,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x20]    ;*getfield upper {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@65 (line 86)
0x00007f0628f5c147:   test   ebx,ebx
0x00007f0628f5c149:   je     0x00007f0628f5c400           ;*putfield left {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@14 (line 79)
0x00007f0628f5c14f:   cmp    BYTE PTR [r15+0x38],0x0
0x00007f0628f5c154:   jne    0x00007f0628f5c1fe
0x00007f0628f5c15a:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbx+0x20],r14d
0x00007f0628f5c15e:   mov    r10,rbx
0x00007f0628f5c161:   mov    r11,r14
0x00007f0628f5c164:   xor    r11,r10
0x00007f0628f5c167:   shr    r11,0x14
0x00007f0628f5c16b:   test   r11,r11
0x00007f0628f5c16e:   je     0x00007f0628f5c18f
0x00007f0628f5c170:   test   r14d,r14d
0x00007f0628f5c173:   je     0x00007f0628f5c18f
0x00007f0628f5c175:   shr    r10,0x9
0x00007f0628f5c179:   movabs rdi,0x7f063c735000
0x00007f0628f5c183:   add    rdi,r10
0x00007f0628f5c186:   cmp    BYTE PTR [rdi],0x4
0x00007f0628f5c189:   jne    0x00007f0628f5c264           ;*putfield upper {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@68 (line 86)
0x00007f0628f5c18f:   mov    r14d,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x20]    ;*getfield upper {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@72 (line 87)
0x00007f0628f5c193:   test   r14d,r14d
0x00007f0628f5c196:   je     0x00007f0628f5c410           ;*putfield left {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@14 (line 79)
0x00007f0628f5c19c:   cmp    BYTE PTR [r15+0x38],0x0
0x00007f0628f5c1a1:   jne    0x00007f0628f5c231
0x00007f0628f5c1a7:   mov    DWORD PTR [r14+0x24],ebx
0x00007f0628f5c1ab:   mov    r10,rbx
0x00007f0628f5c1ae:   mov    r11,r14
0x00007f0628f5c1b1:   xor    r10,r11
0x00007f0628f5c1b4:   shr    r10,0x14
0x00007f0628f5c1b8:   test   r10,r10
0x00007f0628f5c1bb:   je     0x00007f0628f5c1db
0x00007f0628f5c1bd:   test   ebx,ebx
0x00007f0628f5c1bf:   je     0x00007f0628f5c1db
0x00007f0628f5c1c1:   shr    r11,0x9
0x00007f0628f5c1c5:   movabs rdi,0x7f063c735000
0x00007f0628f5c1cf:   add    rdi,r11
0x00007f0628f5c1d2:   cmp    BYTE PTR [rdi],0x4
0x00007f0628f5c1d5:   jne    0x00007f0628f5c2a6           ;*putfield lower {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@79 (line 87)
0x00007f0628f5c1db:   mov    r10d,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x14]    ;*getfield columnHead {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@83 (line 88)
0x00007f0628f5c1df:   dec    DWORD PTR [r10+0xc]          ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007f0628f5c490
                                                          ;*goto {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@100 (line 89)
0x00007f0628f5c1e3:   mov    ebp,DWORD PTR [rbp+0x1c]     ;*putfield left {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@14 (line 79)
0x00007f0628f5c1e6:   mov    r10,QWORD PTR [r15+0x350]    ; ImmutableOopMap {rbp=NarrowOop r13=NarrowOop [0]=Oop [8]=Oop }
                                                          ;*goto {reexecute=1 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - (reexecute) de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@100 (line 89)
0x00007f0628f5c1ed:   test   DWORD PTR [r10],eax          ;*goto {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@100 (line 89)
                                                          ;   {poll}
0x00007f0628f5c1f0:   cmp    ebp,r13d
0x00007f0628f5c1f3:   je     0x00007f0628f5c10c           ;*if_acmpeq {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                          ; - de.famiru.dlx.MatrixEntry::coverColumn@57 (line 84)


perf stat -d -d -d bin/app report for the fast version:
         944020.43 msec task-clock                       #    1.002 CPUs utilized                                                                                                                                  
             34131      context-switches                 #   36.155 /sec                                                                                                                                           
              3772      cpu-migrations                   #    3.996 /sec                                                                                                                                           
             26375      page-faults                      #   27.939 /sec                                                                                                                                           
     3073656028927      cycles                           #    3.256 GHz                      (61.54%)                                                                                                              
     8314592091084      instructions                     #    2.71  insn per cycle           (69.23%)                                                                                                              
     1617667532435      branches                         #    1.714 G/sec                    (69.23%)                                                                                                              
        7376429842      branch-misses                    #    0.46% of all branches          (69.23%)                                                                                                              
     2518602003849      L1-dcache-loads                  #    2.668 G/sec                    (69.23%)                                                                                                              
      217124852119      L1-dcache-load-misses            #    8.62% of all L1-dcache accesses  (69.23%)                                                                                                            
        8360116079      LLC-loads                        #    8.856 M/sec                    (69.23%)                                                                                                              
          36950592      LLC-load-misses                  #    0.44% of all LL-cache accesses  (69.24%)                                                                                                             
   <not supported>      L1-icache-loads                                                                                                                                                                            
         613369051      L1-icache-load-misses                                                (69.23%)                                                                                                              
     2518014639585      dTLB-loads                       #    2.667 G/sec                    (69.24%)                                                                                                              
           2964075      dTLB-load-misses                 #    0.00% of all dTLB cache accesses  (61.54%)
           4335821      iTLB-loads                       #    4.593 K/sec                    (61.54%)    
           1578713      iTLB-load-misses                 #   36.41% of all iTLB cache accesses  (61.54%)

and for the slow version:
        1011635.24 msec task-clock                       #    1.001 CPUs utilized          
             37371      context-switches                 #   36.941 /sec                   
              1949      cpu-migrations                   #    1.927 /sec                   
             26087      page-faults                      #   25.787 /sec                   
     3277438029589      cycles                           #    3.240 GHz                      (61.54%)
     9156368782029      instructions                     #    2.79  insn per cycle           (69.23%)
     1614775762524      branches                         #    1.596 G/sec                    (69.23%)
        7360324323      branch-misses                    #    0.46% of all branches          (69.23%)
     2914029260930      L1-dcache-loads                  #    2.881 G/sec                    (69.23%)
      216220083510      L1-dcache-load-misses            #    7.42% of all L1-dcache accesses  (69.23%)
        8079066223      LLC-loads                        #    7.986 M/sec                    (69.23%)
          47018889      LLC-load-misses                  #    0.58% of all LL-cache accesses  (69.23%)
   <not supported>      L1-icache-loads                                             
         650941335      L1-icache-load-misses                                                (69.23%)
     2913664329244      dTLB-loads                       #    2.880 G/sec                    (69.23%)
           2913507      dTLB-load-misses                 #    0.00% of all dTLB cache accesses  (61.54%)
           4294995      iTLB-loads                       #    4.246 K/sec                    (61.54%)
           1796205      iTLB-load-misses                 #   41.82% of all iTLB cache accesses  (61.54%)

Branch misses are only 0.46% (in both cases), but perf stat highlights the iTLB-load-misses, which is 36% vs 42%.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
